# Logging: Slf4j flush()?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, flush, slf4j

I need to flush all slf4j loggers, is it possible to do so without using implementation-specific code (like in [How do you flush a buffered log4j FileAppender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060240/how-do-you-flush-a-buffered-log4j-fileappender) ?  (I use slf4j-log4j12 ver. 1.5.11)

*Re-formulated:*  How can I flush appenders in slf4j API?

Actually I think there's no way, see my RFE at http://bugzilla.slf4j.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211 .
But rather asking for the case I missed something.

If I opt to use Log4j API, I could try either of two solutions from here:
[How do you flush a buffered log4j FileAppender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060240/how-do-you-flush-a-buffered-log4j-fileappender)

Thanks,
Ondra

Comment: Your question has the answer. What is that you are trying to ask??

Comment: Uhm.. sorry for making it syntactically difficult. Re-formulating above.

Comment: I resorted to turning off the FileAppender's buffer, or setting it to 64 bytes.