# log4j log file not updating

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I have a Java spring application in maven framework running in Tomacat.

**IDE: Eclipse**

Created a **`log4j.properties file`** and put it in a folder called 'log'. Right clicked on the log folder.

```
Selected 'Build Path --> Use as source folder'
```

Below given is my **`log4j.properties`**.

```
log = /log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%t-%x-%-5p-%-10c:%m%n
```

This is the way I followed for logging

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName());
log.info("sample");
```

My issue is

```
1. While maven install, log file created in D:\log4j\log.out
2. I deleted the file. then run the application
3. Now file created. But no content. Its size is 0 KB.
4. When I stop the application, the file is updated with the content.
```

Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2):

No mistake, your log is working fine. The log file is buffered.

See [How do you flush a buffered log4j FileAppender?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060240/how-do-you-flush-a-buffered-log4j-fileappender).